# React doesn’t rerender component if already rendered once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called ChildComponent which I call from ParentComponent as below. Point to be noted:

1. There is a button "Show Child".
2. On the first Click of this button it should do a fresh rerender of the child component. But on Subsequent clicks, it should not even Call ChildComponent but instead fetch the dom from this.refs. For this I am using `return this.refs.chid` which gives error

Below is the code.

```
ParentComponent= React.creatClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      rendered: false
    }
  },
  render_or_cache: function(){
    if (this.state.rendered){
      return this.refs.child;
    }
    else {
      return <ChildComponent/>
    }
  },
  onbuttonclick: function(){
    this.setState({rendered: true})
  },
  render:function(){
    return (
      <div ref="child">
        {this.render_or_cache()}
      </div>
      <button onClick={this.onbuttonclick()}>Show Child Again</button>
    )
  }
})

ChildComponent= React.creatClass({
  render:function(){
    return (
      <div>Some Text from Child</div>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: There's a reason why people format their code: so other people can read the code.

Comment: ^ agreed. Try to edit your code to a more easy to read format

Comment: Can you explain your end goal? Why should `ChildComponent` not re-render? Should *all* instances of `ChildComponent` render only once, or is the question how to prevent a specific subtree of `ParentComponent` from re-rendering?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What if the ChildComponent has a input box that was populated by the user on initial rendering. Now again if the user clicks on "Show Child Again" button, it rerenders the childcomponent and the value in the input box is lost

Comment: My intention is to persist the data. i.e. value in the input box. That is why I dont want a fresh render to happen  for the childcomponent because in that case the value in the input box will be lost

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your component inside `state`

Try out this

**Code:**

```
ParentComponent= React.creatClass({
getInitialState: function(){
   return {
             childComponent :[]
          }
},

onbuttonclick: function(){
   this.setState({childComponent.concat(<ChildComponent/>)})
}
render:function(){

return (
      <div ref="child">
           {this.state.childComponent}
     </div>
     <button onClick={this.onbuttonclick()}>Show Child Again</button>
)}
})

ChildComponent= React.creatClass({
render:function(){

return (
        <div>Some Text from Child</div>
)}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some inconsistencies in your term usage.

*Mounting* is when a component didn't use to exist, and then exists. Mounting starts from initial state and includes a render.

*Rerendering* happens when the properties/state of a component change, but the component hierarchy does not change. This preserves the component state.

I'm not sure how you're trying to accomplish what you say by returning `this.refs.child`. A simple way to accomplish a single-time effect like this is to simply conditionally render the element, like so:

```
render:function(){
const child = (this.state.rendered) ? <ChildComponent/> : ""

return (
      <div>
           {child}
     </div>
     <button onClick={this.onbuttonclick()}>Show Child Again</button>
)}
})
```

Do note that in this approach, changing `rendered` from true to false will cause `ChildComponent` to unmount, losing the state of that component instance. I imagine in most cases this would be wanted behavior.

Comment: Ya thanks for it. What id the ChildComponent has a input box that was populated by the user on initial rendering. Now again if the user clicks on "Show Child Again" button, it rerenders the childcomponent and the value in the input box is lost.

Answer (score 0):

> When to Use Refs
>
> There are a few good use cases for refs:
>
> Managing focus, text selection, or media playback. Triggering
>   imperative animations. Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.
>   Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.
>
> For example, instead of exposing open() and close() methods on a
>   Dialog component, pass an isOpen prop to it.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

For your purpose you can use conditional rendering by checking your state and deciding which component you should render.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're jumping hoops to achieve something that React already does really well; determine when to re-render your component and when to update the DOM.

If you know better than React when to re-render a component, you can define a `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` method on your component that takes the next props and state of your component and returns `true` or `false` based on your own rules.

See the lifecycle methods in the React documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate